# Box-Shadow transition bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am stumbled on a strange bug, for which I have a workaround, yet I would like to see, if any one knows if this is indeed a bug, or I am missing something obvious here.

I have a div, with the following css:

```
notification.brand-notification .inner-notification-box {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10002;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding: 2vw;
    bottom: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


notification.brand-notification.active .inner-notification-box {
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

When opening the `.inner-notification-box` div, by adding the `active` class to `notification.brand-notification`, everything works correctly.

When closing the div, I tried to add a javascript event callback, that will cleanup the HTML code, after the animation finished, writing the following javascript code:

```
this.innerbox.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
        function(e) {
            console.log(e.originalEvent.propertyName);
            if (destroy == true) {
                selfRef.dom.remove();
            } else selfRef.dom.removeClass('hiding');
        });
```

The strange thing that is happening to me, that this javascript event, fires twice, for two different css properties. One of the properties that this fires for, is the `bottom` attribute, but it first fires, MUCH sooner, for the `box-shadow` property, which is not even set in this div.

I also tried to explicitly set the `box-shadow` property, to the same value in both states, but the event still fires, almost immediatly the animation started, to a `box-shadow` property, that was not even set.

I am testing this in `Firefox 70.0.1`. Does any one has any idea why the browser is behaving this way? Is this a Firefox bug? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please provide a proper, working [mre], so that we can look at the issue.